# Dot Product: * Command vs. Loop gives different results

Tags: matlab, floating-point, floating-accuracy, dot-product

I have two vectors in Matlab, `z` and `beta`. Vector `z` is a 1x17:

`1  0.430742139435890   0.257372971229541   0.0965909090909091  0.694329541928697   0   0.394960106863064   0   0.100000000000000   1   0.264704325268675   0.387774594078319   0.269207605609567   0.472226643323253   0.750000000000000   0.513121013402805   0.697062571025173`

... and `beta` is a 17x1:

`6.55269487769363e+26
0
0
-56.3867588816768
-2.21310778926413
0
57.0726052009847
0
3.47223691057151e+27
-1.00249317882651e+27
3.38202232046686
1.16425987969027
0.229504956512063
-0.314243264212449
-0.257394312588330
0.498644243389556
-0.852510642195370`

I'm dealing with some singularity issues, and I noticed that if I want to compute the dot product of `z*beta`, I potentially get 2 different solutions.  If I use the `*` command, `z*beta = 18.5045`. If I write a loop to compute the dot product (below), I get a solution of 0.7287.

```
summation=0;
for i=1:17
    addition=z(1,i)*beta(i);
    summation=summation+addition;
end
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Here's a link to the data: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16594701/data.zip

Comment: you can also just use the matlab function "dot" to compute the dot product

Comment: @Amy: I've computed that with both your methods and with method natan posted below (on R2012a), and all three of them give `4.1232e+12`.

Comment: @zplesivcak: The scaling of the variables is likely part of the problem, so the truncated data I gave doesn't show the problem.  I've added a link to the data.  I'm also using R2012a.

Comment: If you really care about *precise* result, maybe try using some *arbitrary precision* library for Matlab; one is [here](http://www.advanpix.com/).

Comment: @zplesivcak: Precision isn't so important, just consistency. I'm building a regression model...the outputs restats computed were small (ex: 0.7287), but when I manually compute the outputs using the beta value from regstats I get much larger values (ex: 18.5045). I'm using the residuals (from regstats) to train another model, so I need those to be consistent with what the regression model is actually predicting (`z*beta`).

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that addition of floating point numbers is **not associative**.  When summing a sequence of numbers of comparable magnitude, this is not usually a problem.  However, in your sequence, most numbers are around 1 or 10, while several entries have magnitude 10^26 or 10^27.  Numerical problems are almost unavoidable in this situation.

The wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems shows a worked example where `(a + b) + c` is not equal to `a + (b + c)`, i.e. demonstrating that the order in which you add up floating point numbers does matter.

I would guess that this is a homework assignment designed to illustrate these exact issues.  If not, I'd ask what the data represents to suss out the appropriate approach.  It would probably be much more productive to find out why such large numbers are being produced in the first place than trying to make sense of the dot product that includes them.

Comment: I'm attempting to build a regression model as part of my research. The huge entries in beta are a result of this. I now know the model is a poor fit, but I was surprised to see differing results for essentially the same computation.

Comment: I would suggest that something is going wrong before the point where you get to the dot product.